# Aligning Google Maps iFrame

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem where setting both left and right margins to auto does not align my iFrame and I can not manage to align another way. Floating it to the right works however and I can set a pixel margin.

This is the iFrame's line of code:

```
<div id="googlemaps">

    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3320.231282230306!2d151.307011!3d-33.67707499999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6b0d54a318442175%3A0x20077e99e79db860!2sTex+Mex+Restaurant+-+Mona+Vale!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1432343110125" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>

    </div>
```

I have tried the following in CSS:

```
iframe {
align-items: center;
}


iframe {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Any answers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following style to the iframe: `display:block`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and yes, my bad I had the display set to block earlier on but removed it during troubleshooting. Anyways, thanks ;)